# Hopf map and submersion

Tags: riemannian-geometry

> Prove that the Hopf map      $\phi:S^3 \to S^2$  with $\phi(x,y)=(2x\bar y,|x|^2-|y|^2)$  is a submersion.

I need to show for that map rank $d\phi=2$. But how can I find partial derivative of $d(2x\bar y)/dy$. I'm stuck. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

$$
K = x \bar{y} = (a + bi) (u - vi) = au + bv + (bu - av) i
$$

$$
\partial K / \partial u  = a + bi \\
\partial K / \partial v  = b - ai \\
$$

It may be easiest to write out a $4 \times 4$ real determinant rather than a $2 \times 2$ complex one.